# Creating a Ruby on Rails application initialization trivia

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am preparing a trivia for my teammates, to have some fun and refresh knowledge about Rails application initialization process :)

I need to plant a "pig" somewhere, along the way in a Rails application. Something that doesn't blow up the application, but makes it behaving little weird. I already got some ideas, but I want to hear yours.

So I got a question for programmers with some experience under their belt with Ruby on Rails: where would you put a line of code, that would be evaluated while the application starts up? One line that won't break it, but will add an unexpected feature or two?

Answer (score 3):

There's a few places, most obviously `config/initializers/` and least obviously `config/boot.rb` which is where you're not supposed to put things.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a plugin and mount it in the vendor directory, which change some rails behaviour..